# Fix incorrect [apache-spark] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

So somebody changed all [spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark) tags to [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark), but that also replaced all the [spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark) tags that were intended for [flex-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex-spark) and [spark-view-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-view-engine).

Would it be possible to take all questions which are tagged (for example) [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex) or [adobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe) and also [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark) and revise that [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark) tag to point to [flex-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flex-spark) instead?

And similarly [asp-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-net) or [asp-net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-net-mvc), change [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark) to [spark-view-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spark-view-engine).

This is for literally thousands of questions, so manual retagging seems .. not .. good.

UPDATE: Is something .. happening with this? There was a little flurry of comments and then nothing. And someone closed a similar question as duplicate saying "this question already has an answer" when clearly it does not (somebody should change the "marked as duplicate" closing text to be different when the duplicate question has not been answered.)

Comment: When did the mass-editing happen?

Comment: Note that `spark` has been synonymised to `apache-spark` since October last year...

Comment: It certainly happened awhile back, I only noticed it because somebody showed a chart in a presentation that apache-spark was the most popular ETL-based tag on StackOverflow, which seemed .. off to me. And lo it was.

Comment: I don't mind the synonymizing, it's just fairly obvious that large swaths of apache-spark tags should be replaced by flex-spark tags, and you could use sibling tags as an easy way to identify those replacements.

Comment: @JonClements Does that mean no one's mass editing them, it's just the tag synonym silent conversion?

Comment: @approxiblue looks like it

Comment: I believe this question can be closed. As far as I can tell I've been able to fix most of the mistagged entries.

Comment: @zero323 Still tons of apache-spark entries that are actually related to http://sparkjava.com/ - just saying

Comment: @KyleHale Could you provide example urls/tags?

Comment: @zero323 Looking deeper, definitely not tons, I can handle the ones I found. Thanks for all the work you did!

Comment: @KyleHale I am glad to hear that. There can be some leftovers here and there but I don't think it is a serious issue anymore. There are some other problems, like Apache Spark related questions marked with [tag:spark-java], but these can be handled on an ongoing basis.